# Condoms in care packages = questions about sex?

Tags: discussion, scope

I have a question about providing condoms in care packages that my church is doing for our outgoing seniors.  It's a larger question but for this meta-Q, I'll note that *it specifically is not seeking an opinion on whether it's okay*, but rather it is a question about parents' experience with the logistics of undertaking this and the parts related to it, which I'd lay out in the question.

I'm afraid that, while it fits in the framework of the Help Center, **it does loosely relate to 'sex,'** which is considered off-topic in the Center.

I'm new to Parenting.SE, but I love SE and figured this community will provide better answers than any other around the web.  But I don't want to be off-topic.

As recommended by Bugs, I'm including a [link the question](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/29592/condoms-in-a-care-package-parents-advice) I ended up asking.

Comment: I am not sure the appropriate place to put this, but a person who works for the Adolescent Sexual Health Equity Program stumbled upon the original question, found me on Facebook (?!) and procured 10 condoms per package as well as some example literature mini-flyers.  I am fine with the close-votes, but very happy as a single father of a young child that there is a community like this (I'll be asking a lot of questions in the coming years).

Comment: That's a really cool outcome! I am glad that you found more than you expected by asking on here (even if the question was closed eventually). Thanks for joining up :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're right, [our off-topic list includes sex](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). However, this is generally interpreted as questions related to how to become pregnant, or those that don't have anything to do with a parent-child issue. (Ref. [sex](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sex), [sexual-education](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sexual-education), [sexual-development](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sexual-development)...)

An adult child asking how to discuss sleeping arrangements when visiting their parents with their partner, that would be on topic. An adult asking about whether to move in with their partner, or if they have sex often enough, or whether a particular position improves fertility -- all off-topic.

So assuming your question meets general SE standards for not being too subjective, not being too broad, etc., it would probably be topical :) Keep in mind that since you're not *the parent* in this scenario, it can be a little tougher to frame a question that fits, but it should be possible to find a way to phrase it acceptably.

Answer (score 1):

I think this question has provided this community with some good material and even though there has been conversation that has been off-topic, on the whole I think it has added something.

I think it is off-topic -- but only by a hair. Personally, I think that being slightly less rigid about topics is good for us. I upvoted the question because I hoped it would not be closed.

I am also seeing some new-to-Parenting SE posters and think that is also most excellent for the community.

Comment: As an update - it has been voted to be closed, but I accept it: I don't see close votes as a negative thing; I'll try to see if it can be adjusted to be on-topic, but if it clearly isn't, then that's okay and I'll abandon it.

Answer (score 1):

I personally don't feel the question is on-topic but it is a difficult one. The conflict is I feel it's a great question.

My reason for it being off-topic is not the sex aspect but the fact it's opinion based. Whether you want it to be or not your question is going to attract opinions.

> As parents, is there literature or packaging that should accompany these in the care packages?

To answer that it would require my opinion of what I feel, as a parent, should be included. There isn't any *factual evidence* of what should be included and so all I can provide is my two cents worth.

<sup>As a side note, although obvious to some it's worth providing a link to the question you're talking about (even if edited in after) to provide context and/or coverage.</sup>

Comment: I understand that the question is (rightly) going to be closed - I'd love an idea how to frame it correctly.  Has Parenting.SE considered a sandbox for questions?  Other sites have them, where you can get input on how to improve a question, in Meta.

Comment: @Mikey I'm unsure to be honest but it would be useful. I see it on SO quite often and it can definitely be beneficial. Maybe one of the mods knows more.

Comment: @Mikey You are always welcome to post the text of your question in Meta first and say "Here's what I'm going to ask, will it be closed?" -- I see no reason why not to do so in cases where you are unsure. (Mods would probably need to curate a little aggressively to make sure people address _topicality_ instead of _answering your question_, but I'm fine with that.)

Answer (score -3):

Be aware that answers that answer your question, but then go on to discuss or challenge your premises, are considered acceptable here according to other meta questions and answers.

Comment: Absolutely.  Like other SE sites, if it answers the question, I have no problem if it challenges my assumptions.  I would even incorporate those into an edit, if they're helping improve the question.

Comment: This isn't an answer to the meta question that was asked :\